# Are there well-accepted attempts of people to create complexity classes in continuous time?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, complexity

I'm not in CS theory, but I've talked to a complexity theorist recently who, in passing, suggested that my research (not really analog computing, but hypercomputation using physical systems in continuous time) would benefit from examinations of its complexity classes in continuous time. I'm aware that the complexity theory community largely operates under the implicit assumption of ideal Turing machines where discrete steps make sense, but have there been any successful/largely-accepted attempts to develop complexity classes for non-Turing based computation in continuous time?

I know models exist, like [this one](https://binds.cs.umass.edu/papers/1999_Siegelmann_PhysRevLett.pdf), but I don't know how well received they were and whether there are notable complexity theorists working on this.

Comment: Yin Tat Lee and Santosh Vempala recently taught a course on continuous algorithms, which you might find helpful, although I don't know enough about it to say if it has a satisfying theory of complexity classes.  Here's the course, which also contains a draft textbook: https://santoshv.github.io/contalgos.html